# How to split single column value with other data between parenthesis into a multiple columns DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, pyodbc

I recently decided to get my hands on Python again (after 7+ years) but I'm currently struggling to achieve something could've been done in matter of seconds using MATLAB (the programing language I used most of the time). My goal is to query a MS Access DB and save the results so I can sort, filter, and manipulate the data later on.

I have successfully queried the DB (using pyodbc) and stored the queries output in the variable "db_out".
I have confirmed that the query returned 48 results, comprised of 13 columns and the type is a list.

```
print(len(db_out)) --> 48
print(len(db_out[0])) --> 13
print(type(db_out)) --> <class 'list'>
```

I proceed to convert my list to a DataFrame with the help of Pandas Library.

```
my_data_frame = df = pd.DataFrame(db_out)
print(my_data_frame)
```

But it seems the columns separation is not being passed through the DataFrame since I get this (when I print the variable):

```
                                                    0

0   [1, Name1, N, CAN, None, C, None, KDI1...
1   [1, Name2, N, CAN, None, C, None, KDI1...
.
.
.
47   [1, Name48, N, CAN, None, C, None, KDI1...
```

Ok, I got the 48 rows (From 0 to 47, but why only one column?. Does it considered the whole thing to be a single string?)

How can I get the DataFrame to become like this (see 2D-Array below):

```
0              1  2    3     4  5   ...    7  8     9       10       11       12
0   1  Name1  N  CAN  None  C  ...  KDI1  1  None  100000  17700.0  20200.0
1   1  Name2  N  CAN  None  C  ...  KDI1  2  None  100000  17700.0  20200.0
.
.
.
47   1  Name1  N  CAN  None  C  ...  KDI1  2  None  100000  17700.0  20200.0
```

I have tried a bunch of stuff (with my limited knowledge of Python) and cannot figure out how to get this done.

What really confuses me is that I can print "db_out" and get this:

```
[(1, 'Name1', 'N', 'CAN', None, 'C', None, 'KDI1', 1, None, 100000, 17700.0, 20200.0), (1, 'Name2', 'N', 'CAN', None, 'C', None, 'KDI1', 1, None, 100000, 17700.0, 20200.0), . . . Until the 48th query output.
```

And by literally copying the printed result above and saving it in a variable allows the DataFrame to have the structure I need.

After some automated suggestion from Stackoverflow, I tried the following:

```
columns = ['col1','col2',...'col13']
my_new_data_frame=pd.DataFrame(db_out,columns=columns)
```

But I get this error:

ValueError: Shape of passed values is (48, 1), indices imply (48, 13)

Comment: What is the type of `db_out[0]`?

Comment: Hi @Barmar, ```print(type(ref_ific[0])) returns <class 'pyodbc.Row'>.``` Thoughts?

Comment: Stackoverflow recommended to look at a previous topic. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54644342/how-to-convert-list-of-lists-into-a-pandas-dataframe-in-python , however, I think due to the parenthesis I'm not technically passing a list of lists.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52730968/python-pyodbc-row-to-list

Comment: Thanks for the link @Barmar. I will give it a try and see how that works, however, I tried a similar approach and I still encountered some issues. Due to the lack of time on my end I will leave it with the "pd.read_sql_query" implementation I posted in the original post since that seems to be working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

It seems I figured out a way to get the desired output structure.  At the moment of saving the queries results (using pyodbc) I was iterating through the queries:

```
    query_result = []
    for x in cur.fetchall():
        query_result.append(x)
```

I replaced the iteration above created the DataFrame directly with pd.read_sql_query, giving me the structure I was expecting!!